# mongodb atlas search embedded document and project only the matched array elements

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-atlas-search

I have a mongo db collection structured something like below.

```
{
_id,
name,
companies: [{
name,
rating
address
}]

}
```

I have created a atlas index of the type embedded on the field companies.name, when I query using this index, I get the whole document in the results including all the elements of the array that were not a match. How can I project or even find out which array element was the match. I cannot use highlights, since its not supported with embedded document datatype. I can $unwind the results from my aggregation pipeline, but then I have to do the matching myself on the name fields. Other option for me is to restructure the document, but that has other implications.  What are my options here ?, all I need is to findout which element was the match.

Here is my query.

```
let query1 = {
      '$search': {
          'index': 'businessname',
          'embeddedDocument': {
            'path': 'companies', 
            'operator': {
              'queryString': {
                'defaultPath': 'companies.name', 
                'query': `${tags} ~ 2`
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
 let project = {
      '$project': {
        '_id': 1,
        'displayName': 1,
        'email': 1,
        'companies.$': 1
      }

    }
```

I get the below error when using companies.$: 1
MongoServerError: Invalid $project :: caused by :: Cannot use positional projection in aggregation projection

Comment: Have you tried using the [$elemMatch](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/#-elemmatch--projection-) projection operator?

Comment: For $elemMatch, wont I have to specify a condition ? and I do not have a condition, I also tried $ positional projection operator (updated the code above), but i get the error: MongoServerError: Invalid $project :: caused by :: Cannot use positional projection in aggregation projection

Comment: yes, to find out which element matched, use the same match criteria in the elemMatch

Comment: So you are suggesting to use Atlas text search in elemMatch ?

Comment: If that works, sure.  I was thinking it would be trivial to convert the query shown to a regular expression for the elemMatch, since it is not possible to use an index a projection stage anyway.

Comment: Not possible. Only solution for now is to do the searching in the application itself. Using Fuse for it

Answer (score 0):

Doing a `$match` for data in an array always returns the whole array.   To return only the matched element, add another stage to `$filter`:

```
db.foo.aggregate([
    {$match: {"companies.name":"X5"}},
    {$project: {
        company: {$filter: {input: '$companies', cond: {$eq:['$$this.name','X5']}}}
    }}  
]);
```

If you know that your query should yield only 1 item (e.g. in this case, `companies.name` is unique in the array), then you can make it slightly easier by returning a single object instead of an array of 1:

```
    {$project: {
        X: {$arrayElemAt:[{$filter: {input: '$companies', cond: {$eq:['$$this.name','X5']}}\
},0]}
    }}
```

Comment: I am using Atlas search query with fuzzy operators, how can I use it in the filter ?

Comment: Does a `regex` `$match` work as the primary stage?
Even if not, you can always `$filter` output in a stage after `$search`.

Comment: First stage has to be Atlas search. I am thinking of doing a fuzzy search in my application to filter on the returned array.